# SQLite UPDATE only one record matching a WHERE clause, with MAX on another filed

Tags: sqlite, sql-update, max, where-clause, sql-max

Need to modify the data in an SQLite database that has fields similar to:

```
  hash     (string)
  modTime  (long, time in ms)
  data     (any data, e.g. string)
```

I know the hash value of the record to set the data for (it's really xxHash of some binary blob). There can be several records with the same hash, but I need to modify only the one with MAX(modTime) value with the matching hash... Can't figure out how to construct the UPDATE command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `NOT EXISTS` in the `WHERE` clause:

```
UPDATE tablename
SET data = new_data
WHERE hash = ? 
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM tablename t WHERE t.hash = tablename.hash AND t.modTime > tablename.modTime)
```

Or use the column [`rowid`](https://www.sqlite.org/rowidtable.html) to find the row that you want to update:

```
UPDATE tablename
SET data = new_data
WHERE rowid = (SELECT rowid FROM tablename WHERE hash = ? ORDER BY modTime DESC LIMIT 1)
```

or with `FIRST_VALUE()` window function:

```
UPDATE tablename
SET data = new_data
WHERE rowid = (SELECT DISTINCT FIRST_VALUE(rowid) OVER (ORDER BY modTime DESC) FROM tablename WHERE hash = ?)
```

Replace `new_data` with the new value of `data` and `?` with the value of `hash` you search for.

Comment: Thank you, @forpas, an excellent answer, offering all these options. Particularly since in my naivete, years ago I created these databases using "WITHOUT ROWID" clause. So now I have a choice to either update the databases and include rowid (which may be also useful for other purposes in the future, or use your 1st answer!